# Python Sprapy - CSS Selector - Why using .get() intead .extract

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

First of all thanks for all support, that community has given to an old man, but a newbie on Python.  My thanks.

I am doing a course, and I am trying to understand each word of the code.  If something it´s not clear to me, I search for an answer.

I read the [scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors) and do not understand why the `.get()` instead of the other options.

I am doing a **scrapy spider**.  Right now getting the **next page**.

### The problem: why .get()

```
next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
```

#### I Was Expecting

```
next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)')
```

or...

```
next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract()
```

### Here is the HTML Code

> The HTML Code is just to clear the Information.  You can access the [quotes.toscrape.com](http://quotes.toscrape.com/)

```
<li class="next">
    <a href="/page/2/">
    "Next "
        <span aria-hidden="true">→</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

### Here is my full Spider code

> I think the community does not need this but want to give more info as I can.  Thanks.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import QuotetutorialItem

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = QuotetutorialItem()
        all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')
        for quotes in all_div_quotes:

            title = quotes.css('span.text::text').extract()
            author = quotes.css('.author::text').extract()
            tag = quotes.css('.tag::text').extract()

            items['title'] = title
            items['author'] = author
            items['tag'] = tag

            yield items

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()

        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback= self.parse)
```

Thanks a lot.

Sorry for another dumb question.

I can delete this post if it´s better for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the docs**

> If you’re a long-time Scrapy user, you’re probably familiar with .extract() and
> `.extract_first()` selector methods. Many blog posts and tutorials are using them as well. These methods are still supported by Scrapy, there are no plans to deprecate them.
> However, Scrapy usage docs are now written using `.get()` and `.getall()` methods. We feel that these new methods result in a more concise and readable code.

If you don't use `get()`, `getall()`, `extract()` or `extract_first()` then you only have a query. 
**For example:**

`response.css('li.next a::attr(href)')` tells what you want to get. It's a query. Think of it as "please find these elements in the html". The spider will find them, but you need to get them if you want to assign them to a variable. So you use
`get()` if you want only one result, `getAll()`  if you want all the results. You can also use `extract()` and `extract_first()`.

So the final result is:

`next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()`

which gets you the url for the next page.

Comment: Thanks for your Feeback and Time.  So ```.get() ``` and ```.extract_first() ``` it´s the same thing?

Comment: Exactly, they just use get() in the docs now for newer versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your effort and time.  Take care!